# Почему bottomsheet на фрагменте прозрачный?

Tags: java, android

Вроде делал все по гайдлайнам от гугла, а при вызове самого боттомшита он накладывается поверх лэйаута фрагмента

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_help, container, false);
    View bottomSheet = v.findViewById(R.id.bottom_shit);
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    final LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.calls);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }


    });
  mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // React to state change
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            // React to dragging events
        }
    });

  return v;
}
```

Comment: а куда он по вашему должен накладываться?

Comment: @xkor на фрагмент на который я его вызываю

Comment: Вы меня запутали. Так должен он по вашему накладываться на лейаут фрагмента или нет? В вопросе вроде хотите что он на что то другое накладывался, в тут отвечаете что и должен на лайаут фрагмента.

Comment: @xkor Видимо неправильно обозначил вопрос. У меня есть лейаут фрагмента на котором я в методе onCreationView обозначил боттомшит. И на этом лейауте он и должен появиться. Точнее он появляется, но прозрачный - за ним видно xml лейаута фрагмента

Comment: Ну так задайте для `R.id.bottom_shit` нужный вам фон, откуда батомшит знает что вам нужен не прозрачный фон. PS: я чтот тож немного тупанул и прочел только содержимое вопроса, а не заголовок, вот и не понял что вас прозрачность не устраивает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фон BottomSheet полностью зависит от вас, он просто отображает вьюху которую вы ему дали поверх лайаута, если у вашей вьюхи прозрачный фон, то она и будет отображена с таким фоном. Так что просто задайте ей нужный вам фон.

Comment: Если вы о setBackgroundColor() то не помогает. Все равно прозрачный но с оттенком цвета, который я выбрал

Comment: да и в лейауте если менять бекграунд все равно текствью и иже сними просвечивают через цветной боттомшит

Comment: А все, готово. Спасибо за помощь